# How do you attach debugger (or collect Debug output) from running WP app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have a WP8 app with [Fast App Resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) enabled. When the app has been running for an extended period of time, and I tap the icon to resume it, it will immediately exit. I have an unhandled event handler that catches exceptions and uploads them to my server, but it never seems to work in this case.

How do I attach Visual Studio to my application that has been tombstoned so I can determine the cause of this crash on resume?

Comment: Have you tried enabling tombstoning upon deactivation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff806372(v=vs.105).aspx)? Then, just start your app under the debugger, press the start button (debugger will remain attached), re-launch your app from the start tile.

Comment: Hey dude that was it - enabling that option helped me repro the crashing issue. You should post and I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trick is to enable tombstoning upon deactivation first.

See this link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff806372(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff806372%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Then, just start your app under the debugger, press the start button (debugger will remain attached) & re-launch your app from the start tile.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Visual Studio select from the Debug Menu Attach To Process. Select the process amd after the Debugger is attached, press Break all.
Know you can examin the stacks of all threads and check what happened

Comment: I tried this -- the issue is it shows me processes on my computer, not on a Windows Phone Device.